# How to catch AWS EC2 Instance IPs dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, awk, sed, amazon-ec2

How to catch few `AWS EC2` Instances IPs and put them to a script variable if its generates every time randomly and automatically?
I was trying to make it with

```
echo "$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4/) master" >> /etc/hosts
```

but it is just the IP of one of them.
Also was trying with
`aws ec2` describe-instances *...* but don't know how to separate clear IP with other information. Any suggestions with `awk` \ `sed`?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Can you provide more information about what you are trying to achieve and, if possible, why? For example, what do you mean by "catch a few AWS EC2 Instances IPs"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End command is

```
echo "$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name="tag-value",Values="nagios" |grep PrivateIpAddress | awk '{gsub(",","",$2); gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}' | head -n 1) master" >> /file
```

To catch a dynamic ip address from your aws instance with tag and put it to any file

Answer (score 2):

Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) with a `--query` parameter:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{ID:InstanceId,Public:PublicIpAddress,Private:PrivateIpAddress}' --output text
i-2da518a2  172.31.15.3 None
i-6d261640  172.31.27.232   56.64.218.82
i-b3aa3476  172.31.5.0  None
i-6c57c951  172.31.20.243   56.79.129.118
i-192b95c1  172.31.28.76    56.253.207.57
i-af413c91  172.31.27.17    None
```

You can also output as JSON, which is easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to get all the private IP's which are behind a load balancer and pass it to a file.

/usr/bin/aws --output text --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress" ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids `aws --output text --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[0].Instances[*].InstanceId" elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name <loadbalancer name>` > hosts.txt

hope it helps....